# Export Geojson file automatically in folium Draw plugin?

Tags: javascript, python, geojson, folium

I have recently been introduced to [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) and I need to access the exported Geojson file. I found a short code to do for my project.

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import Draw


m = folium.Map()

draw = Draw(
            export=True,
            filename='data.geojson',
            position='topleft',
            draw_options={'polyline': False,
                          'circlemarker': False,
                          'polygon': False,
                          'marker': False},
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}})

draw.add_to(m)
m
```

It is straightforward.

But I'm wondering if anybody knows if there is any way to save the Geojson file automatically after drawing each polygon without clicking on the export button; since I need to access the properties in real time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options to save the geojson automatically.

1. Change the folium Draw plugin's template to save, or
2. Include a custom js snippet as I demonstrate below

..

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import Draw
m = folium.Map()

draw = Draw(
            export=True,
            filename='data.geojson',
            position='topleft',
            draw_options={'polyline': False,
                          'circlemarker': False,
                          'polygon': False,
                          'marker': False},
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}})

draw.add_to(m)
#Refresh the map html
m.get_root().render()

#modify script tag contents to include layer download on 'layeradd' event
script =f"""
       {m.get_name()}.on('layeradd', function(e) {{
       layer = e.layer;
       if (layer.toGeoJSON()) {{
       document.getElementById('export').click()}} }})"""
e = folium.Element(script)
html = m.get_root()
html.script.add_child(e)
m
```

Comment: Thanks, but still ask for file, I need to save file without gui popup save dialog

Comment: You must change your default browser's download settings